# VBA Loop Calculation Logical Error

Tags: vba, excel, foreach

I am trying to create a VBA macro to calculate daily settlements for accounting purposes.
So to explain the context.  I first download a statement which contains data in the following format

E.g.

#### `Memo          FileId     amt`

- `Total       File1     amt`
- `A           File1     amt`
- `B           File1     amt`
- `C           File1     amt`
- `D           File1     amt`
- `Total       File2     amt`
- `C           File2     amt`
- `D           File1     amt`

Where A+B+C have to account for the total and they are not necessarily all there (for e.g. there may only be B or C)

Now I want to calculate the value of each B, C and D for each fileid (This is unique)
And then delete these rows and create a single row which includes the sum on the B and C as the amount.

I have started with the following logical loop here.  I am aware that this is resulting in an infinite loop however I cannot resolve the issue here.

```
For Each ACell In rng
        Do While (ACell.Offset(0, 1).Value = ACell.Offset(1, 1).Value) 'here my intention is to check all the files in the range not just the one below.
        
        If (ACell.Value = "B") Then
            tempCalc = tempCalc + ACell.Offset(0, 2).Value
            ACell.EntireRow.Delete
        ElseIf (ACell.Value = "C") Then
            tempCalc = tempCalc + ACell.Offset(0, 2).Value
            ACell.EntireRow.Delete
        ElseIf (ACell.Value = "D") Then
            tempCalc = tempCalc + ACell.Offset(0, 2).Value
            ACell.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
        ACell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
        ACell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "Summed B C D"
        ACell.Offset(1, 2).Value = tempCalc
        tempCalc = 0
    Loop
Next ACell
```

Can you kindly advise of any possible logical errors here?

Comment: What range does `rng` represent?  I am assuming it is the column holding "A", "C", "Total"?

Comment: yes range is refering to that column.  I have set that to be entered by the user at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a horrible time reading your code. So first some recommendations that will hopefully make the issue stand out.

- Don't iterate over a `Range` implicitly.  By default this will iterate over `rng.Cells` but it looks like you really want to iterate over the cells of the first column.
- Just don't iterate over cells like this.  Your action should be uniform for each item that you are iterating over.  Use the row index instead.
- Don't use `cell.Offset`.  I have never found a useful implementation for it.  Declare a `Const` specifying the column index `Const FILE_ID_COL As String = "B"` etc.
- Use the `AND` operator to chain predicates instead of `ElseIf` if the clause is the same for each time.

#### Issues

- You are inserting rows into the range that you are iterating over.  Do you want to iterate over the inserted rows aswell?
- You are inserting rows for sums while the **file ID** is still the same.  Perhaps you should move that outside the while loop?

Perhaps this is what you mean to do?

```
While row_index < row_count

    tempCalc = 0

    While (rng.cells(row_index, FILE_ID_COL).Value _
           = rng.cells(row_index + 1, FILE_ID_COL).Value) 

       If rng.cells(row_index, MEMO_COL).Value <> "Total" Then
           tempCalc = tempCalc +  rng.cells(row_index, AMNT_COL).Value 
           ACell.EntireRow.Delete
       EndIf

       row_index = row_index + 1

    Wend

    rng.rows(row_index).Insert shift:=xlDown
    rng.cells(row_index, MEMO_COL).Value = "Summed B C D"
    rng.cells(row_index, AMNT_COL).Value = tempCalc
    row_index = row_index + 1 

Wend
```

Comment: how can I obtain row_index and count please?  I has been suggested the "for each" method in another question here and got used to that, but I fully understand its limitations now.  Thanks for pointing issues in my code, weren't clear in my head before.

Comment: I have used `elseif`, because I do not want to sum all the other entries except from total, therefore in the while loop i keep iterating while the `fileid` is the same and add B C D.

Comment: The if statement sums everything but the `"Total"`. `<>` is the _not equals_ operator.  Having multiple predicates result in the same clause is redundant.
Set row_index to the row number to where ever the data starts.